# Prove a normed vector space is finite dimensional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I just came out of an exam which had this question (sorry if the phrasing is a little off). I'm wondering if someone could roughly tell me the steps for proving this / was my attempt even on the right track?

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Prove that if the surface of a sphere is a subset of $X$ and is compact, then $X$ is finite dimensional.

My attempt went something along the lines of:

If $X$ is finite dimensional, then $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. I.e. $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ where $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

We also know that the subset $S $(I.e. the surface of the sphere) is compact, and that the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact. So $f^{-1}(S)=$$X$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: If $X$ is finite dimensional then it is trivial the unit ball is compact. For the converse you have to use the [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma) to show that the unit ball is not compact. There is a proof in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: In this special case can't you just say If $X$ is infinite dimensional, take any countable subspace, choose a normalized  basis $\left \{ v_ {n} \right \}_{n\geq 0}$ and observe that it is a sequence that lies on the surface of the unit sphere but does not converge, and so the surface cannot be compact.